# Left join two tables and if value exists in both tables, keep the latest value from right table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to left join two tables. This part is simple.

I have two tables: product and productupdate

product table looks like this

```
id | productname | description
```

productupdate table looks like this

```
id | productname | descriptionupdate
```

I oversimplified the example. There are more columns, not just those.

```
SELECT productname, description 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN productupdate ON 
product.id =  productupdate.id WHERE id = ?
```

What I want to achieve is to join both tables and if a description update exists in right table (productupdate) keep only the descriptionupdate from productupdate and it should not keep the description from product table.

If I use a left join everything from right tabe will add up to the left table and there will be multiple descriptions from one product.

How should I write the query.

Comment: If *there are multiple updates for a product* is there a date column in `productupdate` table so to find the latest update?

Comment: Hi forpas, There is a date in the product update table.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and order by the date column in `productupdate` descending and get only the 1st row:

```
SELECT 
  p.productname, 
  u.description
FROM product p LEFT JOIN productupdate u 
ON p.id =  u.id 
WHERE p.id = ?
ORDER BY u.datecolumn DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I just made a select in the db and some updates are in the same day. Your answer is good, just as the other answers. I am thinking to add a new column to auto-increment all the rows in the productupdate and then I can order it by last update. I would also change the name of the column descriptionupdate to description and make a UNION between the two tables and get the last update.

Comment: *some updates are in the same day* my code returns only 1 description because of LIMIT 1. I don't think you want more than 1, right?

Comment: but that command does not know which one is the last update. Because the date is made by year-month-day. No hour or minutes.

Comment: So one of them is chosen. If you want more accuracy change the data type of the column to datetime and store hour, min, sec also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT p.productname, COALESCE(pu.descriptionupdate, p.description) AS desciption
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productupdate pu ON p.id =  pu.id 
WHERE p.id = ?
```

Comment: The problem with coalesce is that description and description update have values. None of the is null. Coalesce keeps a value if the other one is null, am I wrong?

Comment: `COALESCE(null, 'item1', 'item2')` returns the first non-null value from the list provided.

Comment: are the values for the pu.descriptionupdate constants or variety of types?

Comment: This is also a good answer. This is the improvement: //// SELECT p.productname, COALESCE((SELECT descriptionupdate FROM productupdate ORDER BY productupdate.date DESC), product.description) AS description
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productupdate pu ON p.id =  pu.id 
WHERE p.id = ? //// date has seconds, minutes, hours, day, month, year

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an IF statement: IF descriptionupdate='' return the description column, else return the descriptionupdate column.

Then, to join all the description, group the results by the id and group concat the column.

```
SELECT IF (descriptionupdate='',description,descriptionupdate) as description
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productupdate pu ON p.id =  pu.id 
WHERE p.id = ?
GROUP BY p.id
GROUP_CONCAT(description SEPARATOR ' ')
```

If you don't want to group all the description, but just the last one, then remove the group part and order the query and limit the result

```
SELECT IF (descriptionupdate='',description,descriptionupdate) as description
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productupdate pu ON p.id =  pu.id 
WHERE p.id = ?
ORDER BY orderColumnName DESC LIMIT 1
```

More info about the control flow functions can be found in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Comment: Hi, Cosmin! Thanks for your answer. There are more description updates on a product. How do I select the last descriptionupdate?

Comment: In that case, you need to use my second query (the one without GROUP_CONCAT). You need to have a way to sort the comments, to find the last one (maybe a column with the comment date, or the last id if you have an autoincrement on the table). Based on that column, you will sort the results and keep only one (that is what `ORDER BY orderColumnName DESC LIMIT 1`) is for.